# How do display a refreshed view without touching it first?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Well, the title already says it all. I have a view (a table view in my special case embedded in a non-table view controller) and at some time in code I want to update cells and display the update. The first part works like a charm but the changes won't displayed after the `reloadData()` - and even when I call `setNeedsDisplay()` afterwards.
When the controller has to update something the tableview will be also re-drawn and the changes are visible. As soon as I touch the tableview cell the changes are also visible. Without touch the update just isn't displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've come across this issue and using GCD should solve it

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.tableView reloadData];
});
```

Comment: On the main thread... Yes, this solves my problem. Thank you. :)

Comment: Glad to hear it @Ryu :-)